# Como exportar o web app angular 2 no servidor remoto?

Tags: angularjs

Olá, pessoal. Eu fiz meu primeiro web app angular 2 e agora estou tentando botar em um servidor remoto para acessar via url. Tentei usando ng build -prod e passei a pasta dist que foi gerada para o meu servidor, porém não funcionou. Me ajudem! Obrigado de antemão!